# How can I round off all the rating, but ignore it if it is null or empty in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I round off all rating but ignore it if its null or 0?

Below is my code:

```
$star = $ratings->count() > 0 ? 
    round($ratings->sum('rating') / $ratings->count(), 2) :
    'No rating yet';
```

Comment: Nice to have you in the community. Welcome Derp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following code

```
$star = $ratings->count() > 0 ? (empty($ratings->sum('rating'))?$ratings->sum('rating'): round($ratings->sum('rating') / $ratings->count(), 2)) : 'No rating yet';
```

I would recommend if you go this  checking in Eloquent Using below code

```
$model = Model::avg('rating'); 
$star = is_null($model->rating)?'No rating yet': round($model->rating,2);
```

The above will be memory-optimized. As the way you were doing it will bring all the records from the Database and Load in the memory. If you only want to show average getting only Average from the Database is more memory optimized and will improve performance later on

Comment: Hello bro thank you for your quick answer. I tried your first solution but its not working, your 2nd solution is working but it doesnt round off the rating. Any idea how to round off your second solution? thank you so much!

Comment: you can do it by using this code
$star = is_null($model->rating)?'No rating yet': round($model->rating,2);

Comment: If the solution is working for you then you can accept the answer. As it will help others when they have the same query and looking for the answer.

Comment: am sorry bro.and thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$star = count($ratings) > 0 ? round($ratings->sum('rating') / $ratings->count(), 2) :'No rating yet';
```

or:

```
public $star='No rating yet';
if($ratings){
    $star = count($ratings) > 0 ? round($ratings->sum('rating') / $ratings->count(), 2) :'No rating yet';
}
```